# Update test case outcome status in azure test plans

Tags: java, junit, azure-devops, automation

I want to update test case outcome status in azure test plans. How can I do this?
I found only how to get info about test plans but without update per test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to update test case outcome status in azure test plans. How can I do this?

When you **manually** update the test case outcome status in azure test plans, you could go to the test run and select more options:

[image]

And if you want update the test case outcome states with REST API, you could try to use following REST API [Results - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=6.0
```

Request Body:

```
[
  {
    "id": 100000,
    "state": "Completed",
    "comment": "Website theme is looking good",
    "associatedBugs": [
      {
        "id": 30
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 100001,
    "state": "Completed",
    "comment": "Website links are failing because of incorrect container id",
    "failureType": "Known Issue"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

with above result API, it's require OAuth-2 authentication. So, unable to make update the test case status not with bearer token or signing information in postman.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).